# Floating Action button to PopupMenu with transformation and animation

Tags: android, floating-action-button

How to proper implement tranformation with animation for Floating Action button to PopupMenu ?

Below there is my fragment of code:

```
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(context, fab);

        popup.getMenu().add("TEST 1");
        popup.getMenu().add("TEST 2");
        popup.getMenu().add("TEST 3");

        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked : " + item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }
        });
        popup.show();//showing popup menu
    }
});
```

Comment: what you want to achieve? is it floating button animation you want? or you want popup animation when popup is open or close?

Comment: Something like that: https://github.com/konifar/fab-transformation but in very simple way